# .NET 5 C# App.config Section names beginning with config are reserved

Tags: c#, .net-5, app-config

I have application in `.NET 5.0` and `App.config` and wanted to add custom config. In previous version of .NET that worked but in `.NET 5.0` doesn't work. This is `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="testProperty" value="aaaa" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

And when I run this app and try to read testProperty:

```
 var testProperty = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testProperty"];
```

I get error:

```
Section names beginning with config are reserved
```

The same code worked in `.NET 4.7.1` but for `.NET 5.0` doesn't work

Comment: Most likely the type of this section is wrong. I mean `System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` < this one. Probably is different in .NET 5

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is answer:
[.NET 6.0 no longer use App.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework)

> As other libraries upgrade to .NET, they'll modernize by supporting
> appsettings.json instead of App.config. For example, logging providers
> in .NET Framework that have been upgraded for .NET 6 no longer use
> App.config for settings. It's good for you to follow their direction
> and also move away from using App.config.